# How to collapse left side panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, panel

I'm looking for a way to make this left side panel collapse. I not looking to have anything else on the map/site to move or adjust. Just to have the left panel collapsable. Ideally with a sliding animation rather than popping in and out. 
[Here's a link to my website with the panel in question](http://www.viceprice.co)

Would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a CSS `transition` on the `left` property to make changes to this value animate smoothly. Then add and remove a class that changes the `left` value to toggle the sidebar's visibility.

```
.left-side-bar {
    transition: left .8s ease-in;
}

.left-side-bar.is-out {
    left: -16.666%; /* equal to the sidebar's width */
}
```

It will be visible by default. Use JavaScript to add/remove the `is-out` class to make it hide.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you might want to do is use an api like Font Awesome to get some cool icons. You could add it with jQuery by the following cdn.

```
$('head').append('<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">');
```

Then create the div, css to hold the hamburger displayed using BS hidden-lg, hidden-md, hidden-sm. To hide it on anything larger than a phone. This would look like this.

```
<div class="mobile_bars hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
<button id="hide_menu">
<i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
</div>
```

You can add this via jQuery, or simply add to your html.

Add the following CSS to your sites CSS to accommodate this element.

```
<style>
.mobile_bars {
    margin-left: 262px;
    margin-top: -32px;
}
```

/* NOTE* you don't need to write the CSS like this, 
sense you'll add with jquery

```
.left-side-bar.is-out */

.push-in {
left: -16.666%; /* equal to the sidebar's width */
}

</style>
```

Then write your script using @keithjgrant code.

```
<script>
// Include Ready function
ALL is .TOUCH deprecated?? 
$('button#hide_menu').on( function(){

$('.left-side-bar').toggle('push-in animated fadeOutLeft');

// For some fun add animated.css to your header and add the following classes as well,
```

or visit https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ to choose a class!

```
});

<script>
```

This wouldn't be my final result but it would get you close. Also I'm assuming your wanting this as a solution for a mobile website, however if your looking to use this a desktop option id simply change the icon, or add a left arrow icon to the right of the logo. Somewhere visible but out of the way!